# Where can I get Malbim on Mishley in English?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mishlei

I am trying to find "Malbim on Mishley: The Commentary of Rabbi Meir Leibush Malbim on the Book of Proverbs".
The book seems to be out of stock. I cannot even find a used version. Any ideas how and where I can get it?

Comment: Most of it is available on google books - https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99/aGv08i6I8l0C?hl=en&gbpv=0

Comment: The formatting is a bit weird and it displays upside down in places but most of it is there

Comment: Looks like you just missed this one https://www.ebay.com/itm/Malbim-on-Mishley-The-Commentary-of-Rabbi-Meir-Leibush-Malbim-on-the-Book-/393032698698

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Glaucon!

Comment: Thank you for the very quick replies. Google Books is a very good start (despite the missing pages)!

Answer (score 2):

Try eichelers here ,seems to be in stock:

https://www.eichlers.com/malbim-on-mishley-pocketsize-hardcover-f280-9.html

Comment: Probably I should have mentioned that I live in Germany. Eichler's shipping costs to Germany are USD 132.

Comment: That seems off,did you try calling them?